# Какие лучше использовать библиотеки для экспорта в pdf на php?

Tags: pdf, php

Какие лучше использовать библиотеки для экспорта в pdf на php со след. условиями:

- поддержка любой кодировки (кириллица);
- примеры работы библиотеки.

Я гуглил информацию, но не нашел интересных вариантов, со всеми была проблема с кодировкой, и передать кириллицу никак не смог.

Может, кто скинет варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую библиотеку mpdf.
С кодировкой и кириллицей проблем не встретил.

в php.ini можно установить параметр:

```
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
```

но не надо:

```
php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
```